# Is there a way to read in a folder of files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, input, file-io, inputstream

I have a folder containing close to 200 word documents, and I want to read them in to C++ using ifstream fin from library fstream.  I have two problems:

1)  fin is able to read in .doc files, but nonsense is printed to the screen because .doc files are not plain text.

2)  I know of no way to get a program to automatically read in multiple files with unrelated file names.

Because of these two problems, I am manually going through each of my .doc files and changing them to .txt files.  In addition, I am calling them 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc, so that I can use a for loop in C++ to read them all in (I would convert the loop control variable i to a string x in each iteration, and read in "x.txt").

While this will work, I've only finished going through 83 files and it's taken around an hour.  Is there a way for me to get C++ to automatically read all these files in?  C++ would have to first change each one to a .txt file as well, so that I can print meaningful text to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost library is very rich for these type of file / filesystem operations. Please check the code below. This basically goes to the folder (ws) where you keep all your doc files, and iterates through all the files in it. The code assumes that the folder 'ws' has *only* files, no folders. Once you have the name of the file you can do all kinds of manipulation on it.

I didn't get why you want to change the extension to txt but included a few lines that does this. Changing the extension won't affect its content.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main(){

    // ref : https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths

    // ws : workspace where you keep all the files
    fs::path ws = fs::path(getenv("HOME")) / "ws";

    // ref : https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-iterators
    fs::directory_iterator it{ws};

    while (it != fs::directory_iterator{}){
        std::cout << "Processing file < " << *it << " >" << std::endl;
        // ... do other stuff

        // Parse the current filename into its parts, then change the extension to txt
        // ref : https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << (ws / fs::path(*it).stem()).native() << ".txt";

        fs::path new_path(ss.str());

        std::cout << "Copying into < " << new_path << " >" << std::endl;

        // ref : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html
        fs::copy_file(*it++, new_path, fs::copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile with this :

```
g++ -std=c++14 -o main main.cc -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are talking about Microsoft Word and "folder", I guess you are running Windows.

The Windows API provides the `FirstFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` pair of functions, which allow your program to automatically find the names of existing files.  [The official example is named "Listing the Files in a Directory"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx)

On Linux and Unix platforms, there are functions named `opendir` and `readdir` which serve the same purpose.

If you want to write cross-platform code, there are libraries that provide an abstraction layer above the OS functions such as `boost::filesystem`.